# Ajax form updates not working consistently

Tags: php, ajax, forms

On this test page, I want to be able to begin typing an item and smart suggest will help complete it.
Upon changing that field, the item value should be processed via ajax and sent to the div "updatediv".

Right now, it works for some items that are submitted, but not others. It's never the same items that don't work.

index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
    <title>Select to Autocomplete</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.select-to-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function($){
        $(function(){
          $('select').selectToAutocomplete();
          $('#update').change(function(){
            var input = $(this).serialize();
            var parts = input.split('=');
            var box = parts[1];
            $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
                url: 'serverside.php', // JQuery loads serverside.php
                data: 'box=' + box, // Send value of the clicked button
                dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
                success: function(data) // Variable data constains the data we get from serverside
                {
                    $('#updatediv').html(''); // Clear #content div
                    $('#updatediv').append(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
          });
        });
      })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
      }
    .ui-autocomplete {
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 218px;
      border: 1px solid #B0BECA;
      max-height: 350px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item a {
      border-top: 1px solid #B0BECA;
      display: block;
      padding: 4px 6px;
      color: #353D44;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item:first-child a {
      border-top: none;
    }
    .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-hover {
      background-color: #D5E5F4;
      color: #161A1C;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 20px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1>Update</h1>
<form id="update">
    <table cellpadding="10" width="800">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"><div class="form_result" style="color:#ff0000; font-weight: bold;"> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;" colspan="3">Select an Application:
                <select name="item" id="selector" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
                    <?php
                        // Connect to db
            $db = new mysqli('user', 'root', 'pword', 'table');

                    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
                        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
                    }

                    // Creating divs
                    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items");

                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['full_name'].'">'.$row['full_name'].'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="height: 10px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="updatediv" style="width:800px;border:1px solid black;">
    </div>
</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

serverside:

```
<?php  

// Get value of clicked button 
$box = $_GET['box'];  
print json_encode($box);

?>
```

Comment: Define: *"It's never the same items that don't work."* - Give us an example.

Comment: For example, say the items to choose from are Apple, Banana and Orange. Sometimes I click Apple and Apple shows up in the update div. Sometimes I click Apple, and it doesn't. Same goes for Banana and Orange.

Comment: It could be the way you have your SQL setup, which is not in your code. All I see is 3 lines.

Comment: True, let me update with the sql setup, thanks

Comment: I fail to see how `$row['name']` and `$row['full_name']` come into play.

Comment: row name and row full name are just the different options i want to show up with smartsuggest because people might search by full name or the abbreviation for full name, which is name.

Comment: How is the search term entered? I can't test any of this "as is" without downloading all JS libraries and setting up a DB. All I see is a `<select>` and no `<input type="text...>` You may need to do `("SELECT * FROM items WHERE search_term='%App'")` or something to that effect.

Comment: Even though it says select, an input type kind of field shows up. I was able to figure it out, but thanks for all your suggestions @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome. And what was it that fixed it?

Comment: Closing the db connection on index.php, although I do not know why :/

Comment: The only way to know for sure, is to put it back the way it was, and if it fails, then there's the problem. ;-) - You may need to make your DB connection "global". I.e.: `global $db;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is really the answer, but after closing the db connection in index.php, the issue went away...